# Terminating Macro From executing further on validation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `method-A()` that is called from multiple methods,

On a condition in method-A, i have to terminate the macro.

i saw one option as `Exit sub` but this will just exit the current `sub ie:method-A()` and the remaining program continues.

how to handle this.

```
Sub mainMethod()
    method-A()
end Sub

Sub method-A()
    if (true) Then
         'Terminate the macro. that is exit method-A() and also mainMethod()
end Sub
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit after comment:
    Just use `end` where you want to terminate ALL code.

```
Sub mainMethod()
    method_A()
end Sub

Sub method-A()
    if (true) Then End
         'Terminate the macro. that is exit method-A() and also mainMethod()
end Sub
```

Original Answer: All you need to do is make methodA a function and return this function as FALSE if you want to exit the main method as per the following code:

```
Sub mainMethod()

    'Run the custom function and if it returns false exit the main method
    If Not method_A Then Exit Sub

    'If method_A returns TRUE then the code keeps going
    MsgBox "Method_A was TRUE!"

End Sub

Function method_A() As Boolean
    Dim bSomeBool As Boolean

   'Code does stuff
   bSomeBool = True

   'Check your condition
   If bSomeBool Then
       'Set this function as false and exit
       method_A = False
       Exit Function
   End If

    'If bSomeBool = False then keep going
End Function
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that i have multiple function call and not just 1 layer of function call. so this variable approach is not practical

Comment: ohhh that could be... let me check

Comment: Good stuff. It can sometimes be useful to use the first way with an error handler in the main sub for alerts or resetting stored values etc

Comment: ya i actually did show a message box to user before exiting... just i didnt know which exit to use. i also tried to call the `error 1` but it throws another error after the message box i show