# Nested Macros: Scope: how to exit all?

Tags: vba

I current have 2 Macros:

The second macro is called within the first to perform a task. However I have logic within the second macro that states if my variable **LastRow < 3** then exit the sub. This of course takes us immediately back into macro 1. What I desire here is to then exit *immediately macro 1 as well*. The way I have attempted to do this is by making LastRow public within both macros.. so when we exit back into macro 1, we have:

```
sub macro1()
application.run("macro2")
    if LastRow < 3 then
    exit sub
end sub
```

where macro 2()

```
sub macro1()

    Static LastRow As Long

        if LastRow < 3 then
        exit sub
else do something
end if
    end sub
```

I believe I may the issue may be that **Static** is not giving macro 1 access to variable LastRow.

whats the best way to proceed?

Regards!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminating Macro From executing further on validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827273/terminating-macro-from-executing-further-on-validation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `End statement` in this way:

```
sub macro2()

    Static LastRow As Long

    if LastRow < 3 then
        '...here is End
        End
    else 
        'do something
    end if
end sub
```

However, `End` has some disadvantages you should be aware of. Let me cite them base on MSDN:

> Terminates execution immediately. Never required by itself but may be
>   placed anywhere in a procedure to end code execution, close files
>   opened with the Open statement and to clear variables.
>
> When executed, the End statement resets all module-level variables and
>   all static local variables in all modules. To preserve the value of
>   these variables, use the Stop statement instead. You can then resume
>   execution while preserving the value of those variables.
>
> The End statement provides a way to force your program to halt. For
>   normal termination of a Visual Basic program, you should unload all
>   forms. Your program closes as soon as there are no other programs
>   holding references to objects created from your public class modules
>   and no code executing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Function instead of a Sub and return a Boolean for example.

```
Function macro2() As Boolean
'returns false if the last row is 2 or less, true otherwise

    LastRow As Long

    if LastRow >= 3 then
        macro2 = True
        'do something
    end if
End Function
```

Then in your first macro:

```
sub macro1()
    if Not macro2 Then Exit Sub
end sub
```

Comment: Where your code says "do something" within the function, are you saying as long as the function returns true or false it can also perform actions like a sub routine can?

Comment: @user1717622 Yes the function will execute normally until its last statement, and the calling code (macro1) will receive a value of True - my "do something" is the same as your "do something" in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable in the first macro and pass it ByRef to the second macro.

```
Sub Mac1()

    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Mac2 lLastRow

    If Not IsTooBig(lLastRow) Then
        'do stuff
    End If

End Sub

Sub Mac2(ByRef lLastRow As Long)

    lLastRow = 5

    If IsTooBig(lLastRow) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Function IsTooBig(ByVal lLastRow As Long) As Boolean

    IsTooBig = lLastRow >= 5

End Function
```

ByRef means that whatever changes you make to lLastRow in Mac2 will be reflected in lLastRow in Mac1.